# FOSUserBundle Entity constuct

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have entity **User** which extends **FOSUserBundle**.

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
...
    protected $ref_id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", length="11")
...
```

**ref_id** comes from cookies variable **ref_id**. How can i pass this value to entity **User** each times new user is registering. Do i have to override **registerAction** or create constructor  on entity **User** and somehow pass **ref_id** there ?

Additionaly, i need to validate (check from database) **ref_id** every time new user is registering. How can i do that ?

```
    class User extends BaseUser
    {
    ...
       public function __construct()
       {
           $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
```

This example doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify `onSuccess` method of `RegistrationFormHandler` class. Check *Overriding Form Handlers* section of the [doc](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md). In your overridden method you just have to add

```
$user->setRefId($this->request->cookies->get('ref_id'));
```

Right before calling the parent's `onSuccess` method.

As for validation you have to create custom validation constraint where you have to inject `@request` and `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` services to get the cookie and validate it across the database. You can check this [cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html).